# Does RabbitMQ support execution of process from queue by time?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

Can I store time in RabbitMQ for call handler in this time? Does RabbitMQ support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's supported, but only via extra plugin.

[There is more dateiled about that](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/)

Simply saying you need to install `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange` plugin, and add new header to your message:

```
byte[] messageBodyBytes = "delayed payload".getBytes();
AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder props = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder();
headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headers.put("x-delay", 5000);
props.headers(headers);
channel.basicPublish("my-exchange", "", props.build(), messageBodyBytes);
```

So you need to put `x-delay` value with milliseconds after this message should be processed.

Comment: Maybe you can recommend me another alternative mechanism in Python? When user can put event(date) in queue for further execution?

Comment: How to get date from storage and put this to Countdown EAT? Need I ping database every time none stop?

Comment: This way that you suggested does not support delay time in datetime format, just milliseconds

Comment: What the problem to convert ? Of course if time for execution is not months ...
What is the task you are trying to resolve ?
Probably it will be enought for you to use database and cron for every 1 (or 5 minutes) to check whether event happened.

Comment: I must caution that, while RabbitMQ may support it, this is definitely non-standard architecture. The purpose of a queue is to match varying workloads with relatively constant processing capacity. Things like delays, etc. only frustrate the purpose of a message queue.  If there is a delay necessary, it is best to implement that in your application logic.